# Save and Edit ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a ViewModel which is joined by three Entities to get data from all entities into one view form. Although i succeeded to implement the same. But i have no idea how to Edit and Save data back to the database. My model classes are joined by one to one relationship.

My Models are:

```
public class Doctor
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speciality { get; set; }

    public virtual DoctorAddress DoctorAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual DoctorCharge DoctorCharge { get; set; }
    public virtual DoctorAvailablity DoctorAvailablity { get; set; }

}

public class DoctorAddress
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}

public class DoctorCharge
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public decimal OPDCharge { get; set; }
    public decimal IPDCharge { get; set; }

    public virtual Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
}
```

My ViewModel is:

```
public class DoctorViewModel
{
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public DoctorAddress DoctorAddress { get; set; }
    public DoctorCharge DoctorCharge { get; set; }


    //Doctor attributes
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Speciality { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfJoinig { get; set; }

    //DoctorAddress attributes
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    //DoctorCharge attributes
    public decimal OPDCharge { get; set; }
    public decimal OPDRevisitCharge { get; set; }


}
```

My Controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(DoctorDetailsViewModel doctorViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var d = new Doctor()
             {
                 Name =doctorViewModel.Doctor.Name,
                 Speciality = doctorViewModel.Speciality,
                 DateOfJoinig = doctorViewModel.DateOfJoinig

             };

            var da = new DoctorAddress()
            {
                DoctorId = doctorViewModel.DoctorId,
                Address = doctorViewModel.Address,
                City = doctorViewModel.City
            };


            var dc = new DoctorCharge()
            {
                DoctorId = doctorViewModel.DoctorId,
                OPDCharge = doctorViewModel.OPDCharge,
                OPDRevisitCharge = doctorViewModel.OPDRevisitCharge
            };

            db.Doctors.Add(d);
            db.DoctorAddress.Add(da);
            db.DoctorCharges.Add(dc);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(doctorViewModel);
    }
```

My View is:

```
@model HospitalManagementSystem.Models.Doctor

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<fieldset>
<legend>Doctor</legend>

<div class="editor-label">
   Name
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   Speciality 
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Speciality)
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
   DateOfJoinig 
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfJoinig)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DoctorId)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    Address
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.Address)
</div> 
<div class="editor-label">
    Area
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.Area)
</div> 
<div class="editor-label">
    City
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorAddress.City)
</div> 
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DoctorId)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    OPD Charge
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorCharge.OPDCharge)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    OPDRevisitCharge 
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DoctorCharge.OPDRevisitCharge)
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
 </p>
</fieldset>        
 }
```

I am getting error message on saving :"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `HM.ViewModels.DoctorDetailsViewModel`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `HM.Models.Doctor`"

Please help me how do i do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting error message on saving :"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'HM.ViewModels.DoctorDetailsViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'HM.Models.Doctor'".

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
@model HospitalManagementSystem.Models.Doctor
```

Claims that the View is expecting a ViewModel of type `Doctor` (Entity), but this line:

```
return View(doctorViewModel);
```

Is actually passing a `DoctorDetailsViewModel` object as the ViewModel.

Try to change your ViewModel type to `DoctorDetailsViewModel`:

```
@model DoctorDetailsViewModel
```

Comment: I tried changing the same you told but data is not saved and redirected to the same page when i click "Create". No sign of errors!

Comment: It could be that your `ModelState.IsValid` is false.